# How can I add a source control folder to an existing team project in TFS 2010?

Tags: team-foundation-server

I have a team project named "ABC web" without a corresponding source control folder. If I double-click on the source control element in Team Explorer it says:

> No Source Control Folder
>
> Cannot open $/ABC web. Source control has not been configured for this team project, you do not have permission to access it, or the team project has been moved or deleted.

If i try to add a file to "$/ABC web/test.txt" using tf.exe it says:

> TF10175: The team project folder $/ABC web does not exist. Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator and ask that it be created.

How can I create the team project folder?

Comment: I just encountered exactly the same issue the other day and immediately sought help from experts. They just posted the workaround yesterday. see https://msmvps.com/blogs/vstsblog/archive/2010/11/03/how-to-add-a-source-control-folder-to-an-existing-team-project.aspx Sorry, the link to command line utility in msmvps web page was expired :-(. Can someone post an equivalent solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just encountered exactly the same issue the other day and immediately sought help from experts. They just posted the workaround yesterday. see https://msmvps.com/blogs/vstsblog/archive/2010/11/03/how-to-add-a-source-control-folder-to-an-existing-team-project.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In TFS2008, New Team Project Creation wizard contained an option called **do not create a source control folder at this time** which creates Team Project without configuring corresponding source control folder.TFS2010 doesn't contain this option anymore.

I think in TFS2008, this project may have been created with above configuration.

Comment: That is the most likely cause, but is there a way to fix it, i.e., create a source control folder for it?

Comment: I think its not possible to configure the Source Control to your existing to Team Project. The other option is to create a New Team Project with Source Control configuration and move your existing artifacts to new Team Project using TFS Integration Platform(http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

To which TFS usergroup do you belong?

Your account may not have the Read Permissions for Source Control folders.

Comment: I'm in the Team Foundation Administrators group so it shouldn't be a security issue. TFSSecurity shows that I have read permissions on the $/ folder, so it's quite certain that this project has no source control folder.

Comment: Are you using TFS2008 or TFS2010?

If you are using TFS2010, Is it a fresh Install or upgrade from TFS2008?

Comment: It's an upgrade from TFS2008.